# Node-Red Cloudant node connectivity fails

Tags: node-red, cloudant

I have created Node-Red App service on IBM Cloud (Both IAM and legacy authentication mechanism is selected while creating). When the Node-Red instance is created along with it a Cloudant instance is also created. I created a flow with just the Cloudant database node. The cloudant database node is configured as follows. Note that I have selected Service as "External cloudant or couchdb service":

[image: Cloudant node configuration]

I have updated Cloudant connection details by clicking the pencil icon against the server entry.

Now when I deploy this node, I get an error message in debug window as **"TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of null"**.

Now, under Cloudant node configuration, I changed the service option and selected the Cloudant Instance that was created while Node-Red App instance was created. Screenshot as below.

[image: Coudant Node as default cloudant service]

After deploying this change, the cloudant node connects without any error.

What is the issue with connecting to external cloudant database using host/username/password? What does the error indicate?

Following are the logs when error occurs:

```
   2020-06-29T10:54:50.81+0530 [API/4] OUT Updated app with guid b745521a-795c-4329-b48e-7409991263aa ({"state"=>"STARTED"})
   2020-06-29T10:54:51.22+0530 [CELL/0] OUT Cell 3043fbb9-6cc0-4c9e-92f2-8cbc93c6e237 creating container for instance 9ff39876-673d-4195-79af-4df8
   2020-06-29T10:54:53.72+0530 [CELL/0] OUT Cell abd60462-983f-4ada-90d4-cd3b63e1a665 destroying container for instance 2a6452fd-4363-42e0-56f4-95b4
   2020-06-29T10:54:53.82+0530 [RTR/27] OUT node-red-tbapf.mybluemix.net - [2020-06-29T05:23:11.612387127Z] "GET /red/comms HTTP/1.1" 101 0 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36" "10.186.136.34:50859" "169.62.205.138:61162" x_forwarded_for:"49.207.200.44, 10.186.136.34" x_forwarded_proto:"https" vcap_request_id:"228e8283-8f10-4684-469f-04a2995c93f3" response_time:102.212456 gorouter_time:102.212456 app_id:"b745521a-795c-4329-b48e-7409991263aa" app_index:"0" x_global_transaction_id:"9f474cea5ef97abf0f2295bf" true_client_ip:"-" x_b3_traceid:"8b624f8e44c105b4" x_b3_spanid:"8b624f8e44c105b4" x_b3_parentspanid:"-" b3:"8b624f8e44c105b4-8b624f8e44c105b4"
   2020-06-29T10:54:53.82+0530 [RTR/27] OUT 
   2020-06-29T10:54:53.91+0530 [CELL/0] OUT Cell 3043fbb9-6cc0-4c9e-92f2-8cbc93c6e237 successfully created container for instance 9ff39876-673d-4195-79af-4df8
   2020-06-29T10:54:54.03+0530 [PROXY/0] OUT Exit status 137
   2020-06-29T10:54:54.18+0530 [CELL/0] OUT Downloading droplet...
   2020-06-29T10:54:56.27+0530 [CELL/0] OUT Cell abd60462-983f-4ada-90d4-cd3b63e1a665 successfully destroyed container for instance 2a6452fd-4363-42e0-56f4-95b4
   2020-06-29T10:55:02.48+0530 [CELL/0] OUT Downloaded droplet (61.5M)
   2020-06-29T10:55:02.48+0530 [CELL/0] OUT Starting health monitoring of container
   2020-06-29T10:55:13.87+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT > node-red-app@1.1.1 start /home/vcap/app
   2020-06-29T10:55:13.87+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT > node --max-old-space-size=160 index.js --settings ./bluemix-settings.js -v
   2020-06-29T10:55:15.20+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 29 Jun 05:25:15 - Starting Node-RED on IBM Cloud bootstrap
   2020-06-29T10:55:15.20+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 29 Jun 05:25:15 - Loading bluemix-settings.js
   2020-06-29T10:55:15.45+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 29 Jun 05:25:15 - Using Cloudant service: node-red-tbapf-cloudant-1592919092762-43583 db:noderedtbapf prefix:noderedtbapf
   2020-06-29T10:55:16.16+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 29 Jun 05:25:16 - Loading application settings
   2020-06-29T10:55:17.22+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 29 Jun 05:25:17 - Using runtime settings for adminAuth
   2020-06-29T10:55:17.22+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 29 Jun 05:25:17 - Enabling adminAuth security - set NODE_RED_USERNAME and NODE_RED_PASSWORD to change credentials
   2020-06-29T10:55:17.23+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 29 Jun 05:25:17 - Enabling anonymous read-only access - set NODE_RED_GUEST_ACCESS to 'false' to disable
   2020-06-29T10:55:19.56+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 29 Jun 05:25:19 - [info] 
   2020-06-29T10:55:19.56+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT Welcome to Node-RED
   2020-06-29T10:55:19.56+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT ===================
   2020-06-29T10:55:19.59+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 29 Jun 05:25:19 - [info] Node-RED version: v1.0.6
   2020-06-29T10:55:19.60+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 29 Jun 05:25:19 - [info] Node.js  version: v12.18.0
   2020-06-29T10:55:19.61+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 29 Jun 05:25:19 - [info] Linux 4.15.0-106-generic x64 LE
   2020-06-29T10:55:20.70+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 29 Jun 05:25:20 - [info] Loading palette nodes
   2020-06-29T10:55:26.86+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 29 Jun 05:25:26 - [warn] Missing node modules:
   2020-06-29T10:55:26.88+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 29 Jun 05:25:26 - [warn]  - node-red-node-email (1.7.8): e-mail, e-mail in
   2020-06-29T10:55:26.88+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 29 Jun 05:25:26 - [info] Settings file  : /home/vcap/app/bluemix-settings.js
   2020-06-29T10:55:26.90+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 29 Jun 05:25:26 - [info] HTTP Static    : /home/vcap/app/public
   2020-06-29T10:55:26.91+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 29 Jun 05:25:26 - [info] Context store  : 'default' [module=memory]
   2020-06-29T10:55:26.93+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 29 Jun 05:25:26 - [info] Installing module: node-red-node-email, version: 1.7.8
   2020-06-29T10:55:27.51+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 29 Jun 05:25:27 - [info] Server now running at http://127.0.0.1:8080/red/
   2020-06-29T10:55:27.64+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 29 Jun 05:25:27 - [warn] 
   2020-06-29T10:55:27.64+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT ---------------------------------------------------------------------
   2020-06-29T10:55:27.64+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT Your flow credentials file is encrypted using a system-generated key.
   2020-06-29T10:55:27.64+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT If the system-generated key is lost for any reason, your credentials
   2020-06-29T10:55:27.64+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT file will not be recoverable, you will have to delete it and re-enter
   2020-06-29T10:55:27.64+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT your credentials.
   2020-06-29T10:55:27.64+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT You should set your own key using the 'credentialSecret' option in
   2020-06-29T10:55:27.64+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT your settings file. Node-RED will then re-encrypt your credentials
   2020-06-29T10:55:27.64+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT file using your chosen key the next time you deploy a change.
   2020-06-29T10:55:27.64+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT ---------------------------------------------------------------------
   2020-06-29T10:55:27.72+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 29 Jun 05:25:27 - [info] Starting flows
   2020-06-29T10:55:27.86+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 29 Jun 05:25:27 - [error] [cloudant in:a41c2d3d.3738f] TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of null
   2020-06-29T10:55:27.86+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at module.exports (/home/vcap/deps/0/node_modules/cloudant/lib/reconfigure.js:23:25)
   2020-06-29T10:55:27.86+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at Cloudant (/home/vcap/deps/0/node_modules/cloudant/cloudant.js:47:19)
   2020-06-29T10:55:27.86+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at new CloudantInNode (/home/vcap/deps/0/node_modules/node-red-node-cf-cloudant/77-cloudant-cf.js:246:9)
   2020-06-29T10:55:27.86+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at Object.createNode (/home/vcap/deps/0/node_modules/@node-red/runtime/lib/nodes/flows/util.js:483:31)
   2020-06-29T10:55:27.86+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at Flow.start (/home/vcap/deps/0/node_modules/@node-red/runtime/lib/nodes/flows/Flow.js:193:48)
   2020-06-29T10:55:27.86+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at start (/home/vcap/deps/0/node_modules/@node-red/runtime/lib/nodes/flows/index.js:345:33)
   2020-06-29T10:55:27.86+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
   2020-06-29T10:55:27.89+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 29 Jun 05:25:27 - [info] Started flows
   2020-06-29T10:55:28.34+0530 [CELL/0] OUT Container became healthy
   2020-06-29T10:55:31.86+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 29 Jun 05:25:31 - [audit] {"event":"comms.open","level":98,"timestamp":1593408331862}
   2020-06-29T10:55:32.09+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 29 Jun 05:25:32 - [audit] {"event":"comms.auth.fail","level":98,"timestamp":1593408332091}
   2020-06-29T10:55:32.42+0530 [RTR/8] OUT node-red-tbapf.mybluemix.net - [2020-06-29T05:25:31.319324438Z] "GET /red/comms HTTP/1.1" 101 0 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36" "10.171.2.123:50196" "169.61.185.57:61162" x_forwarded_for:"49.207.200.44, 10.171.2.123" x_forwarded_proto:"https" vcap_request_id:"6033e5f0-32d9-4fe1-5a89-5a12b29b6552" response_time:1.106342 gorouter_time:1.106342 app_id:"b745521a-795c-4329-b48e-7409991263aa" app_index:"0" x_global_transaction_id:"64e02e055ef97b4b635514ed" true_client_ip:"-" x_b3_traceid:"499eded398546dd7" x_b3_spanid:"499eded398546dd7" x_b3_parentspanid:"-" b3:"499eded398546dd7-499eded398546dd7"
   2020-06-29T10:55:32.42+0530 [RTR/8] OUT 
   2020-06-29T10:55:32.46+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 29 Jun 05:25:32 - [audit] {"event":"comms.close","user":null,"session":"mHZzTJr3ZeNL0k0vvBcgdzgYj5iiUaFS","level":98,"timestamp":1593408332466}
   2020-06-29T10:55:32.77+0530 [RTR/9] OUT node-red-tbapf.mybluemix.net - [2020-06-29T05:25:32.397373879Z] "GET /red/auth/login HTTP/1.1" 304 0 0 "https://node-red-tbapf.mybluemix.net/red/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36" "10.171.2.125:55074" "169.61.185.57:61162" x_forwarded_for:"49.207.200.44, 10.171.2.125" x_forwarded_proto:"https" vcap_request_id:"77ed0682-6048-4a13-5d63-5d592fc7d031" response_time:0.374570 gorouter_time:0.000384 app_id:"b745521a-795c-4329-b48e-7409991263aa" app_index:"0" x_global_transaction_id:"5c3f3acf5ef97b4cf152680f" true_client_ip:"-" x_b3_traceid:"9b26ff380f3a144a" x_b3_spanid:"9b26ff380f3a144a" x_b3_parentspanid:"-" b3:"9b26ff380f3a144a-9b26ff380f3a144a"
   2020-06-29T10:55:32.77+0530 [RTR/9] OUT
```

Thank you.

Comment: Do you get any more error in the application logs?

Comment: No, there are no other logs in node red debug window.

Comment: No, I meant the full application logs, in the IBM Cloud web console.

Comment: Thank you for reverting. I have edited this issue to include logs.